# python script not running using AJAX call

Tags: javascript, python

I am calling a python script using AJAX call as follows,the issue am running into is the python script doesn't seem to be running,can anyone provide pointers on how to debug this?what am I doing wrong?

Javascript:-

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "image.py",  //Running this generates line_graph.png
  //data: { param: text}
}).done(function( o ) {
   document.getElementById("myImg").src="line_graph.png";
});
```

HTML:-

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Image</title>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="myImg" src="sample.png" alt="Line graph" width="600" height="600">       
  <script src="image.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the log file of your webserver? It could indicate a permissions or configuration issue.

Comment: I am running it locally on my machine,the python script when run individually runs fine...how can I debug this?pointers? based on your experience what could be the issue?

Comment: Do you have CGI configured, or some sort of WSGI setup? What do you see when you visit "image.py" in your browser? If you just see the Python source code, then your web server is not configured to run Python scripts.

Comment: haliphax - got it..how do I configure my web server to run python scripts?

Comment: That depends on which web server you are running. Here's something to get you started: https://wiki.python.org/moin/CgiScripts Honestly, though, I'd look into using a Python web framework if you're wanting to do anything serious.

Comment: haliphax - are there any detailed and simple steps to get me started?i dont see any installation instructions in the link you shared

Comment: @kemosabee What webserver are you using, Apache? Nginx?

Comment: sdsmith - am using Apache